# jQuery target window and a scrollable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to target the scroll event for both the window and scrollable divs.  Is there a way to do this in one statement?

I've tried...

```
$(window, '.box-scroll').scroll(function() { });
```

Only way I have found is calling them both separately...

```
$(window).scroll(function() { });
$('.box-scroll').scroll(function() { });
```

Comment: So the issue seems to be that you can't select the window (in that manner) and a normal selector at the same time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but you could use $.map to create a jquery object with both window and .boxscroll, like so:

```
var $d = $($.map([$(window), $('.boxscroll')], function(el){return $.makeArray(el)}));
$d.on('scroll', function() { ... });
```

EDIT:  `$(window).add('.box-scroll').scroll(function() { });`

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddled](http://jsbin.com/utazic/1/edit) with it for a while but can't see any reason it wouldn't.

I can suggest a workaround at best, in case you just need a single function.

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){scroller('a');});
  $('.box-scroll').scroll(function(){scroller('b');});

  function scroller(source){$('.box-scroll-inside').html('scrollling'); };
```